# Oracle context index table is empty after changing character set to UTF-8

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-text

We recently changed the character set of our Oracle 11g database to UTF-8. We have some context indexes on documents to enable text search in documents. The following DDL shows an example of one of our context indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX "PROT"."CTX5_UD" ON "PROT"."USERDOCUMENT" ("DOCUMENT")
INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT" PARAMETERS ('SYNC (EVERY "sysdate+1/24") lexer prot_lexer wordlist prot_wordlist NONTRANSACTIONAL');
```

The index synchronizes every hour and I can see in the logs that the synchronization takes indeed place. However, the index table created by Oracle is empty, thus my application that uses the index does not find any matches for search queries on the index. The index was working perfectly fine before changing the character set to UTF-8. I do not have a lot of experience with Oracle. Is there something wrong with my DDL? What could be the cause that the index table is empty?

Comment: How did you change your character set?

Comment: I suggest to recreate the index manually.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit We created a new database from scratch and imported/migrated all our data.

Comment: @Galcoholic We already tried recreating one of the indexes. That didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Did you follow this guide: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I did. I made a full export and full import of my old database based on that guide, however, I could still have made a mistake.